# How to merge a reverted change?

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have the following situation, a big change was pushed to main branch by mistake (it should have been pushed to a new branch). Searching the internet (mainly SO) suggested that the only way to undo that is reverting to a previous revision, so I did that. Then I started a new branch from the revision that was posted to the main one by mistake.

Now the problem is I can't merge the main branch and the new branch because it causes many of the necessary files from the new branch are deleted. Is there some way to keep those files from the new branch while merging it with the main one?

```
?
|\
E F
| |
C D
|/
B
|
A
```

A,B,C,E - main branch

D,F - other branch based on revision B

C - reverting from B to A

? - I want to keep changes from the D,F branch, but I can't because I reverted most of them in revision C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume instead of 'revert', you actually mean 'backout'? So I am assuming 'C' is a backout of 'B'?

What you could do is the following:

1. Backout 'C' again. This will 'backout the backout', so it will restore the contents of 'B' (you may need to do a bit of merging here).
2. After doing the backout of 'C', you should be able to do the merge from the new branch.

Comment: I'm quite sure I used `revert` rather than `backout` before, but your solution worked. I mean, again I used `revert`, but in the way you described above and now I could merge everything.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's possible you reverted all your files and then committed that. 'hg backout' is basically 'commit the inverse of commit X'. If that commit was the last commit you did, reverting all your files would have the same effect.